# Getting a thread's visible window's title

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user-interface, pinvoke

I was wondering how I would go about doing this, as I've tried a myriad of different user32 functions and researched online quite extensively, but unfortunately I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

There is an application that has 5 threads. These threads can easily be accessed via the .NET Process class GetProcessById method, provided the process' PID. However, it does not appear that there is a function that I can use to provide the Thread ID and enumerate its windows (parent or child). One of these threads has a total of 10 windows, 9 hidden and one visible. The title of that visible thread is what I am trying to get at programmatically.

My latest approach has been to grab the process handle, put that through EnumChildWindows, and try to add each of the window handles to a collection that way, but my collection is always empty.

Here's a screenshot of what I see in the ProcessThreadsView tool:

[image]

Is there something I am missing? I emailed the author of the tool to see how he's doing it, but I figured I'd ask you guys to see if there is an established approach.

**Update:** I have tried using GetGUIThreadInfo, this is how I am calling it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GUITHREADINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint flags;
    public IntPtr hwndActive;
    public IntPtr hwndFocus;
    public IntPtr hwndCapture;
    public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
    public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
    public IntPtr hwndCaret;
    public Rect rcCaret;
}

static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateThreadWindowHandlesByProcessId(int processId)
{
    List<IntPtr> threadWindowHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

    foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads)
    {
        GUITHREADINFO threadInfo = new GUITHREADINFO();
        threadInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(threadInfo);
        bool returnValue = GetGUIThreadInfo((uint)thread.Id, out threadInfo);
        threadWindowHandles.Add(threadInfo.hwndActive);
    }

    return threadWindowHandles;
}
```

**Update 2:**

Using EnumThreadWindows, this is what I've got:

```
public delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

private static bool ThreadWindows(IntPtr handle, IntPtr param)
{
    //get window from handle later, testing for now
    logger.Info("foo bar");

    return true;
}

[STAThread]
public void Execute()
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcessName");

    Process processOfInterest = processes[0];

    foreach (ProcessThread thread in processOfInterest.Threads)
    {
        EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, new EnumThreadDelegate(ThreadWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

(Apologies if my previous answer came off harsh; I said "seemingly obvious" because it seemed obvious to me, so I assumed it was also obvious to the OP and thus wrong, but he did not give any details as to what had/hadn't been tried.)

`EnumThreadWindows` is definitely the function you want, and it should work. I was able to replicate the information from ProcessThreadsView using just `EnumThreadWindows` and `IsWindowVisible` for every application running on my system. (Also, keep in mind that "visible" is not the same as "active").

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private delegate bool EnumThreadWindowsProc(IntPtr handle, int param);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(uint threadId, 
    EnumThreadWindowsProc callback, int param);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr handle);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int GetWindowText(
    IntPtr handle, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder caption,
    int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr handle);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var callback = new EnumThreadWindowsProc(Program.ThreadWindows);

    foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in proc.Threads)
        {
            Program.EnumThreadWindows((uint)thread.Id, callback, 0);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool ThreadWindows(IntPtr handle, int param)
{           
    if (Program.IsWindowVisible(handle))
    {
        var length = Program.GetWindowTextLength(handle);
        var caption = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
        Program.GetWindowText(handle, caption, caption.Capacity);

        Console.WriteLine("Got a visible window: {0}", caption);
    }

    return true;
}
```

What exactly are you getting when you try EnumThreadWindows? Does your callback ever fire?

Comment: I have, I've tried both EnumThreadWindows and EnumChildWindows. Both return nothing for my threads.

Comment: @mikel If that is true then your thread is not attached to any top-level windows.

Comment: The callback never fires with code very similar to yours (Update 2 above). I've tried both adding the callback inline and declaring a single one and passing that to every EnumThreadWindows call.

Comment: The call returns true too, so I shouldn't even bother looking at the result of calling Marshal.GetLastWind32Error. What does your callback delegate look like?

Comment: I'll add my interop definitions to my answer. (Note: they are somewhat redundant because I always use attributes in cases where P/Invoke and COM Interop have different defaults.) But they look to be pretty much what you have.

Comment: If you run your code for *every* process do *any* of them fire your callback?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for posting that. Yeah, some do callback. Of 1671 threads, there are 15 callbacks, and none of these 15 handles that return actually have a visible window it seems, as IsWindowVisible evaluates to false for every single one of them.

Comment: If I remove the if to see what comes back from GetWindowText regardless, all I have is a series of internal windows, thread hidden windows and dynamic provider windows. This is on a system where there is quite a bit of stuff open: Visual Studio, SharePoint Designer, Dashboard Designer, Windows Explorer windows, Services, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [`GetGUIThreadInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506.aspx).

**Update**: There are a few things wrong with your p/invoke.

The rect field is wrong (not that it really matters here).  Use this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

rather than `System.Drawing.Rectangle`.

The type declarations for the other fields are off also. It should be like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GUITHREADINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint flags;
    public IntPtr hwndActive;
    public IntPtr hwndFocus;
    public IntPtr hwndCapture;
    public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
    public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
    public IntPtr hwndCaret;
    public Rect rcCaret;
}
```

You would be wise to check your return values and use `SetLastError = true` in your `DllImport`  attribute so that you can discern why the function call failed.  Also, you
should pass the struct by `ref` since you are passing in the struct size.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool GetGUIThreadInfo(uint idThread, ref GUITHREADINFO lpgui);
```

Use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to obtain the error code. But only check this if `GetGUIThreadInfo` returns false.

With the above changes, the call to `GetGUIThreadInfo` will work, when given a valid thread ID. Do also note that the other process needs to have the input focus in order for the `GetGUIThreadInfo` to return anything useful.

> If the specified thread does not exist or have an input queue, the function will fail.

Comment: The thing about this function is that it returns 0 for every one of my threads (when accessing the hwndActive property of the GUITHREADINFO structure), even for the thread that I know is the specific one I am after (ID 6500). So that leaves me wondering if the IDs I am providing it are the right IDs (I am getting these from the collection produced by Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads). The documentation for the function says that I can get the thread IDs using GetWindowThreadProcessId , but I need a window for that, which I don't have...

Comment: So you are passing one of these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.id.aspx  That should work. But I can't see how you are calling GetGUIThreadInfo.P/invoke could be wrong.

Comment: Hmm, P/Invoke is exactly where I looked. I've updated the original question to show you what I've got.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I clearly did not have the right types for the struct, however I was setting the cbSize correctly (we seem to be doing the same thing in our code). The only difference now being that I have to cast from the int that Marshal.SizeOf returns to uint. I am however still getting an error 87, which appears to be related to invalid parameters. I am updating the code from the questions again so you can see what I've got now, after changing the struct. Thanks for all your help thus far.

Comment: The int/uint difference is mostly going to affect the C# side; unless you're talking very large or negative values it will look the same to unmanaged code. But using 'out' when you need 'ref' will completely break your function because the CLR won't copy your initialized structure to unmaanged code, so USER32 will see a cbSize of 0 and fail.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that the thread had to have the input focus. This is definitely not the case for the window that I am trying to get the title for! I should have made the clear before, anyway, thanks for your help David!

Comment: So which window are you looking for? A thread can be attached to many top level windows. Which one do you want?

Comment: I am looking for a window that is visible, yet does not have a focus. In fact there is no input fields in it or anything. I am wrapping around a really old system and unfortunately the window title is the only way for me to determine whether a scheduler is waiting, executing or what.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like it. Now I just gotta figure out why the callback is not being fired. Once I get the window handle there, it should just be a matter of using SendMessage to get the title.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in Update 2 is fine (assuming that `eraAccessProcess` is actually meant to be `processOfInterest`). That code works. The only possible causes for failure that I can see are:

1. `processOfInterest` is not the process that you are actually interested in.
2. That process really has no threads that are associated with windows.

Comment: Yup, I just fixed that, forgot to change that variable name when I pasted it in. When I access this process via ProcessThreadsView, it shows the 5 threads above, and Thread 6500 appears to be the one owning the window in question. So I think it is pretty safe to say that this is indeed the process I want (I have matched the thread IDs in foreach loop to what I see through the tool) and given the output from the tool, it would appear as though the window I want is owned by one of the threads. I am so confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: I ran this code and successfully found a bunch of windows for a Notepad++ process. I'm sure it works. I suggest you try it out for a Notepad process or something like that.

Comment: any ideas as to why I am unable to see anything at all? I tried simply listing all of the windows, as you suggested, and all I get is a series of internal windows and other seemingly irrelevant items.