# C# Trying to enumerate every window for each process thread

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a little application to enumerate in console every window name from each process thread.

I'm currently using this code that works fine on a windows 7 machine but for some reason it stucks at windows 10 without any stack trace or error message, I tried to add almost everything inside a try-catch but I didn't get any message as well so I'm lost.

Here is the code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
        class Program
        {
            private delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                Console.WriteLine("Detected: " + processes.Length + " processes.");
                foreach (Process process in processes)
                {
                    IEnumerable<IntPtr> windowHandles = null;
                    try
                    {
                        windowHandles = EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(process);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        continue;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Checking process" + process.ProcessName);
                    foreach (var handle in windowHandles)
                    {
                        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                        try
                        {
                            SendMessage(handle, 0x000D, message.Capacity, message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (message.Length == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Window name: " + message.ToString());
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(Process process)
            {
                List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();

                ProcessThreadCollection threads = null;
                try
                {
                    threads = process.Threads;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    return handles;
                }

                foreach (ProcessThread thread in threads)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (hWnd, lParam) => { handles.Add(hWnd); return true; }, IntPtr.Zero);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                return handles;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea about why it could stuck?

**UPDATE**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
        class Program
        {
            private delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr handle);

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                Console.WriteLine("Detected: " + processes.Length + " processes.");
                foreach (Process process in processes)
                {
                    IEnumerable<IntPtr> windowHandles = null;
                    try
                    {
                        windowHandles = EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(process);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        continue;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Checking process: " + process.ProcessName);
                    foreach (IntPtr handle in windowHandles)
                    {
                        if (handle == null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!IsWindowVisible(handle))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                        int capacity = 0;
                        try
                        {
                            capacity = message.Capacity;
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                            continue;
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            SendMessage(handle, 0x000D, capacity, message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (message.Length == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Window name: " + message.ToString());
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(Process process)
            {
                List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();

                ProcessThreadCollection threads = null;
                try
                {
                    threads = process.Threads;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    return handles;
                }

                foreach (ProcessThread thread in threads)
                {
                    if (thread == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    int threadId = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        threadId = thread.Id;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        continue;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        EnumThreadWindows(threadId, (hWnd, lParam) => { handles.Add(hWnd); return true; }, IntPtr.Zero);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                return handles;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the way Windows 10 sandboxes applications and apps but I'm not sure.  I know that we can't access in depth the way we use to and I don't know the proper way to do so.  Windows 10 uses a lot of virtual environments to host applications and so I'm just guessing here... Please don't take this as any answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael Pucket II, I tried it at another machine with windows 10 and worked fine, but looks like the code randomly fails too at windows 7 without any message/trace/error... I really I dont know where to start to fix my issue.

Comment: I have one thought.  Your windowHandles = null already.  What's say it the EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(process) doesn't fail but still returns null.  Then when you enter foreach (var handle in windowHandles) it would crash.  You should get an error but if this is deployed you might not.  I would set the windowHandles to an empty enumeration so that the foreach loop will at least have a zero count value and never the chance to be null.  That's the only flaw I've been able to notice immediately and would have to start there if it was me.

Comment: Well, NM. Looking at the EnumerateProcessWindowHandles method it doesn't seem to have a way to return a null... hmmm

Comment: Ok, so my best guess is this is failing at the PInvoke level for some reason.  Maybe add a check to the hWnd value etc before calling the imported methods.  It could be you're sending an invalid value and it fails silently on that end never to show you on yours.  You would think the try / catches would restrict this but I know that's not always the case.  I've had exceptions leap around try / catch for different reasons so it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael Pucket II, I've checked it and looks like it fails at SendMessage for some reason and that stucks the code without any error (I would love to know why).

Also it seems that is caused by some processes and not by the operating system (windows 7, 10).

I also updated the first post, I've added IsWindowVisible (from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318058/getting-a-threads-visible-windows-title) to the code and seems that it works perfectly, but I would like to learn why it happens.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working and thanks for letting me know as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your console application as administrator if the problem still arises I suggest using the API `GetLastError` that's what it does:

> Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error code.

Try reading the value to know the problem , try this link for guidence on how to use it: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but I failed to get any output.